# LEFT OUTER JOIN WHEN IT HAS MULTIPLE TABLE SELECT QUERY

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-navigator

Currently I have joined two tables using inner join , like following

```
SELECT A.*,B.*
FROM A,B
WHERE A.COLUMN_A = B.COLUMN_B
```

now I want to join Left outer join to above results , lets say I want to join Table `C`

So I did like following

```
SELECT A.*,B.*
FROM A,B
LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON B.COLUMN_X =  C.COLUMN_X
WHERE A.COLUMN_A = B.COLUMN_B
```

this is executing without errors in SQL navigator, But in this result I cannot see any output.

anything wrong in this query , please advise

Answer (score 0):

Change it to have proper join syntax like

```
SELECT A.*,B.*
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.COLUMN_A = B.COLUMN_B
LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON B.COLUMN_X =  C.COLUMN_X;
```

Better change all to outer join

```
SELECT A.*,B.*
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.COLUMN_A = B.COLUMN_B
LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON B.COLUMN_X =  C.COLUMN_X;
```

Comment: there is not need to change `inner join` to `left join`. Suppose you have some `A.COLUMN_A` values, which don't exist in `B.COLUMN_B`. Using both Left join, you would get those `A.COLUMN_A` in output whereas using first `INNER JOIN` you would not.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT A.*,B.*,C.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.COLUMN_A = B.COLUMN_B
LEFT OUTER JOIN C 
ON B.COLUMN_X =  C.COLUMN_X
```

If you absolutely have to use legacy syntax, then use this. But I won't recommend it.

```
SELECT A.*,B.*,C.*
FROM A,B,C
where A.COLUMN_A = B.COLUMN_B
AND
B.COLUMN_X =  C.COLUMN_X (+)
```